# How do I import a excel file using Maatwebsite in a vue component?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js

I already did this but in that time I use laravel blade and laravel collective to save the form. Now that I am using vue, It is a bit different for me and too tricky for me to do since im new with vuejs. How can I achieve this? Can I use laravel collective in a vue component so that my job will become easy? Thanks for the answers. Here are my codes.

Vue component

```
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal2" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
              <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                  <h4 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Import CSV</h4>
                  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                  </button>
                </div>
                  <form @submit.prevent="importRoom()">
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label>Select CSV</label>
                      <input
                        v-on:change ="i dont have a method yet"
                        type="file"
                        name="template"
                        id="template"
                        class="form-control"
                        :class="{ 'is-invalid': form.errors.has('template') }"
                      />
                      <has-error :form="form" field="bldg"></has-error>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                </div>
                </form>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
```

My route

```
Route::post('/importRoom','RoomController@import');
```

The Controller

```
 public function import(Request $request){
        if($request->hasFile('template')){
            $path = $request->file('template')->getRealPath();
            $data = \Excel::load($path)->get();

            if($data->count() > 0){
                $rows = $data->toArray();
                foreach ($rows as $row) {
                    $inserts[]=[
                        'room_desc' => $row['room_desc'],
                        'bldg' => $row['bldg'],
                    ];
                }
            }
            $chuncked = array_chunk($inserts, 10);
            if(empty($inserts)){
                dd('Request data does not have any files to import.');  
            }
            else {
                foreach($chuncked as $inserts){
                    \DB::table('rooms')->insert($inserts);
                 }
                dd('record inserted');  
            }
        }
    }
```

method

```
  importRoom(){
            axios.post('/importRoom')
              .then(()=>{
                console.log('imported')
              })
          }
```

I only have two columns in my excel to import in the database. Im really new to client side so its difficult for me. Thanks for helping..

Comment: You've to achieve this with API call using axios.

Comment: yah i need to call the method `importRoom()` right? but in the `onchanged(e)` what should I do there? and also is my code correct in vue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

onchange you've to upload the excel sheet in formData

```
getExcelData(e) {
    const formData = new FormData();
    const file = e.target.files[0];
    formData.append('file', file);
    axios.post('url', formData)
            .then(response => {
                //Code to play with api response with excel data
            })
            .catch(error => {
                //Catch errors
            });
}
```

Comment: should I call also the methos `importRoom()` sir?

Comment: No need you should call getExcelData at @change

Comment: what about the form? after i submit?

Comment: You've to store that response data in some variables and then pass it in form when submitted

Comment: what do you mean by that sir? sorry im a bit confused

Comment: can we chat here sir. I really need get this to be done https://join.slack.com/t/vue-vmr4432/shared_invite/enQtOTAyMjIzODM5NzQ3LTgyY2Q2ODA1ZjRmNTdkZjAwZmMyYjc3NWYzOGRiNWU5NjEwNWYzM2UyZmE0ODk5OTdhY2NkMWZmM2Q2YTBjYjA

Comment: How do you submit a form? You've to make a api call for form submission.

Comment: i submit a form through the method `importRoom()` sir in my methods

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206865/discussion-between-manikandan-and-vince).